# Google Checkout Donation No Shipping

Tags: google-checkout, donations

I am implementing a Donate Now system using Google Checkout. One really frustrating part to figure out is how to not require users to input a shipping address for their donation (since it's a pure donation, no shipping address is required). I found the documentation for Digital Delivery and the ability to add a class to products, but I'm just using the Donate Now form that is generated by Google and have no idea where to add this class to make it so no shipping address is required.

Below is the form I'm using:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/MY_NUMBER" id="BB_BuyButtonForm" method="post" name="BB_BuyButtonForm" onSubmit="return adjustDescription()" target="_top">
    <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="Donation"/>
    <input name="item_description_1" type="hidden" value="Donation Description"/>
    <input name="item_quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input name="item_currency_1" type="hidden" value="USD"/>
    <input name="item_is_modifiable_1" type="hidden" value="true"/>
    <input name="item_min_price_1" type="hidden" value="0.01"/>
    <input name="item_max_price_1" type="hidden" value="25000.0"/>
    <input name="_charset_" type="hidden" value="utf-8"/>
    <input id="item_price_1" class="center" name="item_price_1" type="text" />
    <input disabled style="opacity:0.6;" name="donate_submit" alt="Donate" src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/donateNow.gif?merchant_id=MY_NUMBER&amp;w=115&amp;h=50&amp;style=white&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US" type="image" />
```

So I'm not sure if there's another way to not require a shipping address, but if anyone can tell me where to put the "product-digital" class to accomplish this, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi jrubins, did you find some solution how to do donation button via Google Checkout? The code above does not work.

Comment: @peno still haven't figured out how to not require a shipping address. The code above works to display a button but it still asks the customer for a shipping address